# ActiveModel::Serializer for C# .NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

I like how Rails ActiveModel::Serializer works. It's very simple to define a model serializer ([ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)):

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :body

  has_many :comments
end

class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :body

  belongs_to :post
end
```

Are there any simple way to define a model serializer, whitelisting attributes without messing my Entity Framework database first models?

Comment: You should create a new class with only properties which are used in serialization process.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Rails ActiveModel::Serializer is used to serialize to JSON data.  Entity Framework is not used for this purpose, it serializes to a database.

You want to use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

**Update**

You can the [JsonIgnore](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) attribute to the properties that you do not want to serialize.

```
public class Entity
{
   public int ID { get; set; }

   [JsonIgnore]
   public Entity Parent { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do use it. But when I serialize it goes into infinite loops because the entities are related. So I need to ignore some properties. To do this I need to create a new class and redefine every model property I want it to serialize. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Cool. But when Entity Framework regenerate my database first entities it will remove all the attributes that I added before. Is there a way to keep the attributes that I added?